# How can I make colors to gradually change using UIColor in Objective-C and Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

Right now I have this code, and I want to be able to change the color gradually as the angle of an arc changes.

I want to gradually change from green, to yellow, then orange, then red. But gradually, not just at once.

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
    UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.0 green:1 blue:.0 alpha:0.5];

    UIColor *grayColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    grayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:0.5];

    UIColor *redColor = [UIColor redColor];
    redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:.0 blue:.0 alpha:0.5];

    UIColor *yellowColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    yellowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:.0 alpha:0.5];

    UIColor *orangeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    orangeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.647 blue:.0 alpha:0.5];

    int direction = 0;
    if(index == 3){
        direction = 1;
        CGFloat currentEndAngle = atan2f(d_y, d_x);
        CGFloat actualEndAngle = -0.49234065359; //was M_PI

        if(fabs(currentEndAngle*180/M_PI) <= 91){
            // Draw the optimal arc
            //[self drawArc:ourPoint.startPosition andEndAngle:actualEndAngle andRadius:radius andColor:grayColor andDirection:direction withContext:context];

            if(currentEndAngle > 0 || currentEndAngle > actualEndAngle){
                // Draw the current green arc
                if(currentEndAngle - actualEndAngle < 0.6){
                    [self drawArc:ourPoint.startPosition andEndAngle:currentEndAngle andRadius:radius andColor:orangeColor andDirection:direction withContext:context];
                }
                else{
                    [self drawArc:ourPoint.startPosition andEndAngle:currentEndAngle andRadius:radius andColor:greenColor andDirection:direction withContext:context];
                }

            }
            else{
                // Draw the current red arc
                [self drawArc:ourPoint.startPosition andEndAngle:currentEndAngle andRadius:radius andColor:redColor andDirection:direction withContext:context];
                missAngle += fabs(currentEndAngle-actualEndAngle);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please remove your swift tag. This is not swift code...

Answer (score 0):

As Ckouta says in his answer, what you want is a gradient. I don't think his code would do exactly what you want to do (drawing an arc with a color gradient) but it's a step in the right direction.

Getting an arc to draw using a gradient would be tricky. You'd either need to create custom Core Graphics code to render this yourself, use some combination of CALayers, layer masks, and CAGradientLayers, or maybe use Core Image filters to apply a radial gradient to an arc image.